# visualsvn cannot connect to WMI namespace the RPC server is unavailable

Tags: wmi, windows-server-2008, rpc, visualsvn-server

I did a lot of research for following matter and I got a lot of helpful information but the matter still remains, so I'm going to write it with full details

I'm trying to run "[Remote Server Administration](http://www.visualsvn.com/server/features/remote-admin/)" with VisualSVN Server (Enterprise Edition), the server is Windows Server 2008 connected to the internet via router with port forwarding to this server. The client is not at local network so I use a static IP for the server.

Also I did every things written at this URL: http://www.visualsvn.com/support/topic/00025/
but I still get the following error message `Connot connect to WMI namespace "..." : the RPC server is unavalible (0x800706ba)` when I'm trying to "connecting to another computer".

On the other-hand, I can browsing the "Repositories" content by any web-browser successfully.

How can I manage the Repositories at remote servers?

Answer (score 0):

`"...the RPC server is unavalible (0x800706ba)"` error indicates a connectivity issue to the remote machine.

Accessing WMI remotely requires port 135 TCP/UDP and all TCP ports above 1024 (1024-65535) to be opened (and forwarded), by default. You can setup fixed port for WMI to simplify the port-forwarding / proxy setup task. In order to setup the fixed port, follow steps described in the article ["Setting Up a Fixed Port for WMI"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb219447). After you follow these steps you are required to setup port forwarding and proxy rewrites (if any) for 135 TCP/UDP and port 24158 TCP.

`"...Access is denied (0x80070005)"` error indicates insufficient permissions to access WMI remotely. Add your user account to the local group on the remote machine: "Distributed COM Users".

Comment: Thanks for your support.

I follow your advice but now I've got a new message "Cannot connect to WMI namespace "": Access is denied (0x80070005)"